# Warning: linker path does not have real file for library -lpthread

Tags: c++, sqlite, linker

Ive got the following message trying to compile sqlite3 on MingW64

```
*** Warning: linker path does not have real file for library -lpthread.
*** I have the capability to make that library automatically link in when
*** you link to this library.  But I can only do this if you have a
*** shared version of the library, which you do not appear to have
*** because I did check the linker path looking for a file starting
*** with libpthread and none of the candidates passed a file format test
*** using a file magic. Last file checked: d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib//libpthread.dll.a
*** The inter-library dependencies that have been dropped here will be
*** automatically added whenever a program is linked with this library
*** or is declared to -dlopen it.
```

What does it mean? Do I need libpthread.dll? Where I can get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must not necessarily mean that you don't have `libpthread.dll`, but the paths that the linker is searching do not contain this library. You must either

- locate the file and it ist path to the linking Options
  or
- if it not exists, gather the library and install it.

Search for the file on you computer and if it does not exist, you will need to acquire it.

[This](http://mingw-users.1079350.n2.nabble.com/missing-pthreadGC2-dll-td5533063.html) article might prove useful.